# Knockout.js: child a tags not working when parent li element has click binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a menu that each item toggles it's own submenu, here is the sample code. as you can see submenu item is a tag that links out to google.co.nz

```
  <ul id="menuHolder">
    <li data-bind="click: showMenu.bind($data, 1)"> 
         Main menu item
        <ul class="submenu" data-bind="visible: selected() == '1'">
            <li>
               <a class="sub-item" href="http://google.co.nz">
                    Submenu item
               </a>
             </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var menuModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.selected = ko.observable(0);        
    self.showMenu = function (data) {
        var s = self.selected();
        if (s > 0 && data == s)
            self.selected(0);
        else
            self.selected(data);
    };     
}
ko.applyBindings(new menuModel(), document.getElementById("menuHolder"));
</script>
```

everything works only the a tag no longer works, what's wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is the following: clicking on the link raises the click event which boubles up and gets handled by your `showMenu` function and by default KO won't trigger the default behavour of the browser so your link won't open.

What you need is to add a click event handler on your link which returns `true` this tells KO to trigger the browser default behaviour and you may also need to set `clickBubble` property to `false` to prevent your `showMenu` execution:

```
<a class="sub-item" href="http://google.co.nz"
   data-bind="click: function(){ return true }, clickBubble: false" >
      Submenu item
</a>
```

Can can read more about the click binding in the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html).

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/xRL8j/)